# Hibernate composite logical key on record insert

Tags: java, hibernate

I have the autogenerated `id` field for primary key of the table. I have to keep it by the specs. However, the logical key is `(firstName, lastName)` pair.

In the entity class, I defined the fields as follows:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private long id;

//  @NotNull
//  @Column(nullable = false)
private String firstName; 

private String lastName;
```

and overrode `equals()` and `hashCode()` using `firstName` and `lastName` only.

I want to set it up so that when I attempt to save a record with a `(firstName, lastName)` that is already in the database, it won't save but throw an error. 
Currently,

```
session.save(person);
```

is saving duplicate `(firstName, lastName)` pairs as many as they come. How is this done in Hibernate?

```
@Table(uniqueConstraints=@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"firstName", "lastName"}))
```

didn't achieve it.

Comment: Are your db column names really `firstName` and `lastName`? Not `first_name` and `last_name`?

Comment: @veljkost yes. the entity class field names have the exact same spelling as the db fields. i initially made Hibernate create the table anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'd added

```
@Table(uniqueConstraints=@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"firstName", "lastName"}))
```

after i created the table.

Works.